# Carregar um arquivo TXT no Access, iniciando a leitura a partir da 10ª linha

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Estou carregando via VBA um arquivo TXT para uma tabela do access, mas o arquivo txt tem um cabeçalho com 9 linhas que não preciso, como posso resolver no vba para que o arquivo comece a ser lido a partir da 10ª linha.

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Lembre-se de postar seu código atual, além de indicar eventuais erros.

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma lida nos [métodos relacionados a manipulação de arquivos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/input-and-output-keyword-summary), e parece que não existe nenhum que busca a posição por linha. Existe a operação `seek`, mas ela busca a posição no arquivo por byte (ou seja, mais ou menos por caractere).

Assim, a forma mais simples que eu enxergo de ler a partir da décima linha é adicionar um contador no seu código e só salvar a informação a partir da linha que você quer. Por exemplo (você adapta pra sua realidade):

```
Open "caminhoArquivo" For Input As #1
i = 0
ignorarAteLinha = 9
Do While Not EOF(1)
  i = i + 1
  Line Input #1, conteudoLinha
  If i > ignorarAteLinha then
    Debug.Print conteudoLinha 'Dentro desse if você faz o que precisa
  End if
Loop 
Close #1
```